# Rust macro crate: can't find crate, import resolution is stuck

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-macros, rust-crates

When I try to build my application on one specific machine, I get the following error:

```
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `custom_crate`
 --> examples/basic/src/main.rs:4:5
  |
4 | use custom_crate::custom_macro;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't find crate

error: cannot determine resolution for the attribute macro `custom_macro`
 --> examples/basic/src/main.rs:6:3
  |
6 | #[custom_macro("test")]
  |   ^^^^^^
  |
  = note: import resolution is stuck, try simplifying macro imports
```

- custom_crate is a proc macro lib that I've imported with `path=` in Cargo file.
- I am using rustc and cargo 1.74.0. I installed with rustup toolchain.
- The problematic server uses Ubuntu 20.04.6.

I am confident that my file structure is correct, as it works on every other virtual or physical machine I've tried with the same Rust/compiler versions, code, etc.

- E.g., macro and app are in different crates, macro is exported, macro is included as a dependency with correct path, etc.

The workaround here did not work (and also should not be happening in 1.74.0?): https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/57966

I tried reinstall/uninstall and running build as root. Tried `cargo add` with the crate.

Stuck on other things to try. Are there known issues with, for example, env variables or this version of Ubuntu? Again, I don't get this error with every other machine/OS/etc. that I've tried.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Cargo.toml + all necessary Rust files.

Comment: If it doesn't error with other machines (but same compiler version), this is likely a bug in the compiler. Report an issue.

Comment: Did you run `cargo clean`?

Comment: Thank you! The following worked: (1) it appears that I needed to manually specify the resolver due to cargo / crate version; and (2) cargo clean. I had tried one without the other.